# If I burn Ubuntu onto one of my internal hard drives and boot off it to install it on another hard drive, can I undo it?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I have an internal hard drive that's empty. I want to make that **like** a USB to boot from. But I'm afraid if I create that I cannot undo it and format my HDD, the same way you can't undo burning a movie to a CD. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: You can't undo burning to a CD because CD-R can be written only once. HDD can always be re-formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can use a hard disk drive as a live drive and re-use it afterwards

I have done it many times with HDDs and  SSDs too.

Be very careful to write to the correct target drive (check and double-check to avoid mistakes). It is a good idea to have a **backup** of everything, that you cannot afford to lose.

- In Linux I use mkusb for this purpose, both to make a live-only drive or persistent live drive and to wipe the first mibibyte or restore it to a standard storage device. See this link,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

  You may want to use **gparted** after wiping the first mibibyte in order to create a more advanced partition table.
- In Windows I use Win32 Disk Imager to make a live-only drive (for installing purposes). See this link,

  [wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)

  You can use other software too, for example Rufus, which is recommended officially by Ubuntu,

  [rufus.akeo.ie](https://rufus.akeo.ie)

  **Edit:** I am not sure, if the tools in Windows will write to an internal drive, or if the HDD or SSD must be connected via USB (and an adapter or external box). If problems with one tool, let us try another one, in order to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Hard disks and SSDs can always be wiped clean after use, short of a hardware failure. Several ways to do this exist:

- **`dd`** -- The `dd` command is a sort of "nuclear option" for wiping disks. It copies data from one device to another. You can give it `/dev/zero` as the source to wipe the disk. Thus, something like `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4096` will completely wipe *all* data on `/dev/sdb`. ***This makes the `dd` command potentially very dangerous*** -- but also very useful. (The `bs=4096` part of this command is optional. It tells `dd` to write 4096 bytes at a time. This reduces the time it takes the command to wipe modern Advanced Format disks, which use 4096-byte sectors.) Note that completely wiping a hard disk is likely to take hours. When it's done, the disk will be completely empty. Using this procedure is advisable before you sell a hard disk or hand it over for recycling, to ensure you've erased all personal data (credit card numbers, tax returns, passwords, etc.). In your case, it's probably overkill, but it may be an option worth considering if other options don't quite get the job done. Note that a full wipe like this on an SSD will make the SSD think the whole disk is in use. You should probably create a Linux filesystem and then use [`fstrim`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html) on it to ensure that the SSD understands that the disk is now effectively empty.
- **Partial `dd`** -- By adding options to the preceding `dd` command, you can erase *part* of a disk. Most partitioning information resides early on the disk, and this is certain to be true if you used `dd` to copy the `.iso` file to the hard disk to begin with. I don't recall exactly how much data you'd need to erase to wipe a hybrid ISO-9660/MBR or ISO-9660/GPT disk image, but something like `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4096 count=1000` would almost certainly get it all, and would be *much* faster than wiping the whole disk. This approach will *not* erase all the sensitive data on the disk, though. If you partitioned the disk in a conventional way, this would be more than enough to get all MBR data. Some GPT data might lurk at the end of the disk, though....
- **GPT fdisk** -- My GPT fdisk utility suite (installed in the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu), and in particular its `gdisk` and `sgdisk` tools, provide a feature to wipe all GPT data from the disk. This feature will also wipe all MBR data. The easiest way to do this is by typing `sudo sgdisk -Z /dev/sdb`, changing `/dev/sdb` as necessary. This command wipes all the GPT data structures, including both the main data structures at the start of the disk and the backup data structures at the end of the disk. Like a partial `dd` operation, this one leaves sensitive data on the disk, so it's not adequate if you want to "sanitize" a disk before it leaves your possession.

For your purposes, I'd try using either `sgdisk -Z` or a partial `dd` operation. If that fails, a full `dd` of the whole disk might be in order.

Note that there are some exotic cases where something else might be required, in addition to or instead of the preceding. One of these is if something has set the [Host Protected Area (HPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area) feature on the disk. This feature enables part of the disk's space to be hidden from the computer. See the link to the Wikipedia article for details. It sometimes gets set accidentally and must be unset by using the `-N` option to `hdparm`. Another possible complicating factor is if the disk is part of a RAID array, or if your firmware is set to enable RAID. This has an effect that can be similar to HPA, in that a part of the disk is hidden and used to store RAID metadata. In this case, you'd need to use RAID-specific tools (and/or disable the RAID settings in your firmware) to properly use (and delete data from) the affected parts of the disk. Simply writing an Ubuntu `.iso` file to a hard disk will not activate either HPA or RAID settings, though, so chances are you don't need to be concerned with them. I mention them only in case one of these features happens to have been set on your disk in addition to what you're doing, or in case somebody else in the future might have such a problem and stumble across this answer.